# Continuous injection of metric ball into Euclidean ball

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

This is a follow-up to [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321217/continuous-inclusion-of-metric-spaces-of-smaller-capacity/321223?noredirect=1#comment800877_321223).

Suppose that $(X,d_X)$ is a compact metric space with (finite) metric-capacity, defined by 
$$
\kappa_X(\epsilon)\triangleq\sup\left\{
k : \exists x_0,\dots,x_k \in X : \exists r>0, \sqcup_{i=1}^k B(x_i;\epsilon r)\subseteq B(x_0;r)
\right\}
.
$$

If $(\mathbb{R}^D,d_{Euc})$ is a Euclidean space, with $D$ large enough, such that there exists a $C>0$ satisfying
$$
K_X(\epsilon) \leq CK_{\mathbb{R}^D}(\epsilon);\qquad \left(\forall \epsilon \in \Big[0,\frac1{3}\Big)\right).
$$

Does there necessarily exist a *continuous* injection of $(X,d_X)$ into a metric ball in $(\mathbb{R}^D,d_{Euc})$ of some (finite) radius $M>0$?

Comment: A typo... now it's Euclidean space.

Comment: It is well-known that a compact metric space $X$ admits a continuous injection into some Euclidean space if and only if $X$ has finite topological dimension. More precesely, each metrizable separable space $X$ of finite dimension $n$ admits a topological embedding to the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^{2n+1}$.